# Skip routing via lo interface for outgoing packets

Tags: linux, networking, routing

Introduction:

I have following load balancing configuration:
10.0.1.31 - lb
10.0.1.32 - node1 (tomcat + mysql)
10.0.1.33 - node2 (tomcat + mysql)

I'm using keepalived which is redirecting packets to active nodes - shared ip address is 10.0.1.35

of course lb has required config:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

node1 and node2 to handle properly incoming packets needs to have 10.0.1.35 on lo

```
[root@lb-node1 ~]# ip addr list dev lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   inet 10.0.1.35/32 scope global lo
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Problem:

Due to the fact that we have 10.0.1.35 on the lo if the locale tomcat is trying to connect to mysql via lb  - connection is established to local instance.

I would like skipp lo for outgoing packets

Test

From node1 which has disabled mysql service and 10.0.1.35 ip on lo interface I'm trying to conenct to mysql on the node2

telnet 10.0.1.35 3306

unfortunately the result is

```
   [root@lb-node1 ~]# telnet 10.0.1.35 3306
   Trying 10.0.1.35...
   telnet: connect to address 10.0.1.35: Connection refused
```

of course if I remove 10.0.1.35 IP from lo interface I'm able to connect to mysql instance on node2

Solution ?

I was trying do add routes with appropriate metrics but it doesn't help :/

```
    [root@lb-node1 ~]# route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
    10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 lo
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
    0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```